# How to pass child type to generic in parent class C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I am currently consuming a third party dll and have no option to switch off of it or not use it. I have a class that looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class ParentClass<T> : ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<T>
{
    //...stuff
}
```

This causes a few problems if I want to make a Dictionary or return the ParentClass type so that I don't need to know which child class it is beforehand. To make it easier to develop around this I would like to do something like this:

```cs
//ChildClass should be what is passed to the generic, without directly referencing it
public abstract class ParentClass : ApiClass<InheritedClass>
{
    //...stuff
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{

}

//Now I could define a dictionary like
Dictionary<KeyClass, ParentClass> Map;
```

Defining it like the second example would allow me to create a Dictionary as where the first one I'm not sure I can define a Dictionary when I don't have a value for the Generic? A bit more info about the ApiClass, the definition for the ApiClass looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class ApiClass<Wrapper> : OtherApiClass where Wrapper : ApiClass<Wrapper>
{
    //...Stuff
}
```

So in a scenario like this, how would I define my ParentClass without a Generic, but where the type passed to ApiClass is the child class of the ParentClass (the ApiClass explicitly needs the child type)?

Edit: Clarified a bit on the value of InheritedClass

Edit2: I am not looking for alternatives, I am asking for how to. If I pass anything other than the last inherited class (the current ParentClass I defined at the beginning of the question) the Api will crash. If the syntax existed it would look something like

```cs
public abstract class ParentClass : ApiClass<typeof(this)>
```

Comment: The root of your problems seem to be caused by the definition `class ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<T>`. That's a very unusual definition. Is this a class you wrote, or is it something defined in the thrid-party library?

Comment: This is defined by the third-party library and I would really prefer it didn't exist. Unfortunately in order for my ParentClass or any child of it to load properly into their application is has to follow that constraint where it passes itself or the child class as the generic. I don't have or get any access to the source code for it either.

Comment: From that definition, I assume you could just store a `Dictionary<KeyClass, OtherApiClass>`, and cast the value to `ParentClass<T>` when you need specific functionality

Comment: This may not help. It probably won't help. Okay, it won't help. http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson actually, I'm not sure why I didn't think of just using the OtherApiClass in the dictionary instead. That likely solves all of the issues I need for it since I mostly need to reference it in functions and dictionaries. Thanks! I'll  just leave the class as is then even if I want to change it. It's mostly a limitation due to a dependency anyways so.

Answer (score -2):

I imagine that the third-party library you're using defines `ApiClass` like this:

```
public abstract class ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<T>
```

That's an example of the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Let's turn this in to a concrete example:

```
public abstract class ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<T>
{
    public abstract T GetNewInstance();
}
```

If I had that code, I could consume it like this:

```
public class MyApiClass : ApiClass<MyApiClass>
{
    public override MyApiClass GetNewInstance()
    {
        return new MyApiClass();
    }
}
```

This allows `MyApiClass` to have an method, defined as an abstract method in that parent class, that knows about the current instance. Eric Lippert discusses this [here](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/).

It has the downside that it can be abused:

```
public class MyNefariousApiClass : ApiClass<MyApiClass>
{
    public override MyApiClass GetNewInstance()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That's legal, but C# doesn't have a way of enforcing that you use class itself as the generic parameter. If we had `class MyNefariousApiClass : ApiClass<this>` it would, but we don't.

Now, when you say you have a class `public abstract class ParentClass<T> : ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<T>` that that's your code for consuming the third-party library.

If so, then that's not the normal way to consume this pattern. If you're overriding the class it should look like this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T> : ApiClass<T> where T : ParentClass<T>
```

We can then take this to it's final point and define the `ChildClass` like so:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass<ChildClass>
{ }
```

Now, if you want a dictionary that can hold any such `ChildClass` then you are stuck as the parent is generic. The only somewhat sensible workaround is to use an interface.

```
public interface IParent
{ }

public abstract class ParentClass<T> : ApiClass<T>, IParent where T : ParentClass<T> 
{ }
```

Then you can write `Dictionary<KeyClass, IParent> dictionary = new ...`.

Comment: Not sure this really solves anything as I now need an interface with zero functions just to specify it in a Dictionary. As @AndrewWilliamson in the comments, since ApiClass inherits OtherApiClass, I can just specify OtherApiClass. It doesn't get me around the template issue, but unless we had something like
```class Parent : ApiClass<T> where T : ApiClass<typeof(this)>``` I don't really see a way around it. Not sure what I gain by specifying ParentClass<T> instead of ApiClass<T> in the generic either? Is there a benefit to doing this?

Comment: @VextaRelos - The intent of this pattern is to allow the final class to return an instance of itself. If you stick with `ApiClass<T>` then you can't do that. You might have a different need, but that would be why they chose that pattern in the first place. And I made it clear that you can subvert this because C# doesn't allow `class Parent : ApiClass<T> where T : this`.

Comment: I'm a bit perturbed by the two downvotes. I thought this was quite a clear discussion on the pattern in question and the fact that you can't do what you want and you need to settle with an interface - there's no other way.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but yeah it seems there's really not an option to do what I need. It's not that I want to pass the <typeof(this)> to the ApiClass, it's that the ApiClass will literally crash the program if I don't. My project runs as an addin to this Api. I don't have any other option to define the class.

Comment: @VextaRelos - That kind of detail needed to be in your question - including the full code to show what you needed.

Comment: I can certainly add that detail to the question, but I felt it wasn't necessary as I asked how to and not alternatives to. I did specify what I was looking for though I didn't use typeof(this) I used InheritedClass and elaborated on it. It doesn't seem to matter though as there is no way to do what I am asking seemingly.