# C# How to pass child class as generic type in parent class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm working with a 3rd party library which provides a class that takes the current class from which I'm instantiating it as a generic. It looks something like this

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionstring)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // THIS PART HERE
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<BaseContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to inherit from `BaseContext` without having to override OnModeCreating again, but I'm not sure how I'd get my child class to be passed as the generic template in the parent class?
I've tried

```
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<typeof(this)>(modelBuilder);
```

but that doesn't work (for reasons outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225480/how-to-pass-child-type-to-generic-in-parent-class-c-sharp))

Is there an easy solution to this that I'm missing?

Comment: There's no way to do this if you can't modify `BaseContext`; you'll have to override the method (though you're still free to call the base method first and perform custom initialization afterward, if this works). If you can modify `BaseContext` this can be done with `this.GetType()` and `Type.MakeGenericType()`.

Comment: Your best bet is to instantiate what you want outside of this method, then have the parent type be what is asked for as a parameter

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve here. You can provide anyways the "this" as a parameter and in the method self, you can check the type. It depends on what you are really trying to achieve. Try adding more data about the use case and we might be able to help you find a better approach.

Comment: You can create a Factory or extensions and constrain the type using where keyword

Comment: @JeroenMostert how would that look like? AFAIK I can't pass a variable of type Type as a generic template

Comment: `typeof(SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType())`. Using this type is uncomfortable, however, because it's a pure runtime type -- so creating an instance has to go through `Activator.CreateInstance`, calling `Database.SetInitializer` has to be reflected over as well, etc. Not a path you want to take if it can at all be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't completely understand your goal.
Would this be a solution for you?

Create a Factory that is responsible for creating a new object

```
public static class CustomSqliteFactory
{
    public static SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<T> Create<T>(T obj, DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        where T : BaseContext 
    {
        return new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<T>(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
var sqliteConnectionInitializer = CustomSqliteFactory.Create(this, modelBuilder);
```

I wrote my solution using notepad and I hope there is no syntax error

---

Edit

Here is a similar example that achieves your goal: (I have created the print function for demonstration purposes only)

```
public class Parent<TChild>
    where TChild : Parent<TChild>
{
    protected SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<TChild> obj;

    public Parent()
    {
    }

    protected void OnModelCreating()
    {
        this.obj = CustomSqliteFactory.Create<TChild>();
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    public void Print()
    {
        base.OnModelCreating();
        Console.WriteLine($"Child type: {this.obj.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First()}");
    }
}


public static class CustomSqliteFactory
{
    public static SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<T> Create<T>()
        where T : Parent<T>
    {
        return new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<T>();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
var child = new Child();
child.Print();
// Child type: Child
```

Comment: I had to change the return type of the function to `SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<T>`, but other than that it worked! Thanks for the good answer :)

Comment: Great! I have edited the return type in order to keep the answer clean.

Comment: So it turns out your answer doesn't work after all - the factory method keeps using the `BaseContext` as type, even though `obj` is of type of `ChildContext` (inherited from `BaseContext`). I can update my question to provide a bit more context

Comment: Ok, quick solution but not optimal! You can provide the type of child in the constructor and use it in the factory or you can make the class generic somehow. And use T to access the type.

Comment: I have added a new example that should solve your problem. Notice: just for easy testing purposes I have simplified the code but it should work for your solution.

Hope that answers your question